# Get billing information in order review section of one page checkout in Magento

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I am trying to display the billing and shipping information in the "Order Review" section of One Page Checkout in Magento 1.7.0.

However, it just doesn't want to co-operate at all. I tried several methods mentioned in various forums and in SO as well. But none of these methods seem to work.

Here are the ones I have already tried.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/55281/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/55281/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
                                      ->getShippingAddress()
                                      ->getData();


Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
                                      ->getBillingAddress()
                                      ->getData();
```

Will give you arrays with the billing and shipping information for the current order.  Depending on context, you may also have to call

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
                                      ->collectTotals();
```

For the order taxes, subtotals, etc to be correct.

Comment: I had the chance to try this out and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the addresses as objects:

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$billing = $checkout->getBillingAddress();
$shipping = $checkout->getShippingAddress();
```

and show them as html text:

```
echo $billing->format("html");
echo $shipping->format("html");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get Billing information through this code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
                                  ->getBillingAddress()
                                  ->getData();
```